# What do the red ampersands above my character's head mean?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm on Playthrough 2, at Level 50, playing Zero the assassin.  Recently I was doing a quest in Eridium Blight and when I went to jump into my vehicle, I noticed that there were two red ampersands "&&" above Zero's head as he crawled over the hood to get in.

I know that NPCs will have a green exclamation point above their head when you're ready to turn in a mission, but I don't recall ever seeing these red symbols before, and wasn't sure what they mean.  They were gone the next time I exited the vehicle.

Game glitch or actual real indicator of something?

**Edit**:  It just happened again, this time it was one red question mark.  I enabled the quest Monster Mash Part 2 and left Eridium Blight via the exit to The Dust.  After the new map loaded, I exited the vehicle to check my inventory, and when I went to get back in, Zero crawled over the hood and had a red question mark over his head.

Comment: Can you get a screenshot or picture? sounds wierd

Comment: I only notice it when entering the vehicle, and it's gone the next time I exit, so it's going to be tough to capture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of his character animations. They are random, much like the random voices each character has when you open a menu. I can't recall the full list, but I do remember the !, &&, and :D as icons that have shown up.

[Here is a full list](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Zer0#Emoticons) of emoticons that show up.

Comment: [Here's a link](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Zer0#Emoticons) to Zer0's wiki page that lists his (known) face-plate 'emoticons', and their general causes.